# Configuração de e-mail inserida errada no Git, como deletar?

Tags: git

boa tarde, eu estava configurando o git aqui no meu notebook, e errei um dos itens, e ao invés de colocar email, coloquei apenas mail, gostaria de saber se tem como eu deletar essa informação?

Na hora de configurar, coloquei as seguintes informações:

user.name = "Maxwell"

**user.mail = max@gmail**

user.email = max@gmail

Comment: de uma conferida na     [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-unset) eis a instrução `git config --unset user.mail`

Answer (score -1):

Sim, você pode deletar essa informação digitando os seguintes comandos no seu terminal:

```
 git config --global --unset-all user.mail
    git config --global --unset-all user.email
```

Isso irá remover as configurações de "user.mail" e "user.email" do seu arquivo global de configuração do Git.

Se você quiser verificar as configurações atuais do Git, você pode digitar o comando:

```
git config --list --global
```

Ele mostrará todas as configurações globais atuais.

Answer (score -2):

Voce pode configurar novamente suas configurações, passando as credenciais corretas:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Fulano de Tal"
$ git config --global user.email fulanodetal@exemplo.br
```

se remover a flag `--global` você as configura credenciais especificamente para o repositório que estiver fazendo a configuração:

```
$ git config user.name "Fulano de Tal"
$ git config user.email fulanodetal@exemplo.br
```

Ou seja, sem o global você pode utilizar uma identidade diferente para cada projeto/repositório.

ou na raiz do repositório, você pode editar o arquivo de configuração do git:

```
$ sudo vim .git/config
```

e alterar suas credenciais: `user/email`